# Draw rectangle with fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Here is the my code to drawing a rectangle with fabric.js, but i am not getting the exact result. I am using fabric.js to draw a rectangle on the canvas in HTML

```html
<canvas id="canvas2" width=500 height=500 style="height:500px;width:500px;"></canvas>
```

my JS code is:

```html
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas2");
var rectangle, isDown, origX, origY;

canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o){
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);

    isDown = true;
    origX = pointer.x;
    origY = pointer.y;

    rectangle = new fabric.Rect({
        left: origX,
        top: origY,
        fill: '',
        stroke: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 3,
    });
    canvas.add(rectangle);
});

canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o){
    if (!isDown) return;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    canvas.renderAll();
});

canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o){
    isDown = false;
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shariq Ansari, 
For my understanding you have a problem to draw a rectangle with mouse.
Please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wcwabpwc/)

Your problem was with mouse move. This is what you need to do in your mouse:move event:

```
canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o){
    if (!isDown) return;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    if(origX>pointer.x){
        rectangle.set({ left: Math.abs(pointer.x) });
    }
    if(origY>pointer.y){
        rectangle.set({ top: Math.abs(pointer.y) });
    }

    rectangle.set({ width: Math.abs(origX - pointer.x) });
    rectangle.set({ height: Math.abs(origY - pointer.y) });
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```